# Method cannot be called inside of a class

Tags: ruby

This program runs as intended if outside a class, how could this be run inside of one?

```
class Pointester
  $points = 0

  def point_tracker()
    puts $points
  end

  point_tracker()
end
```

Here's the error: undefined method `point_tracker' for Pointester:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. This program does *not* run fine, it should raise a `NoMethodError`, actually.

Comment: I tried running it again outside of the class and the output is 0. Running it as shown above does throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
class Pointester
  $points = 0

  def point_tracker
    puts $points
  end
end

Pointester.new.point_tracker
```

And you might want to consider using an instance instead of a global variable – depending on your use-case.